# Getting error during working with Selenium Grid

Tags: java, automation, selenium-grid

When I am running these two commands in two different Terminal:

1. `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2ar -role hub`
2. `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register`

I am getting message for first command that hub is running and up and for second I am getting message that node is up and running.

But when I checked Grid console in my browser then getting this error:

> DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to 17.168.83.211:5555 [/17.168.83.211] failed: Operation timed out

When I am trying to run my Selenium code:

```
package GoogleTesting;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             DesiredCapabilities cap=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
             cap.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
             try {
                URL url=new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
                WebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver(url,cap);
                driver.get("http://google.com");
                System.out.println("Title is "+driver.getTitle());
                driver.quit(); 
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Then hub is trying to initiate the session with session but it got failed after 2 trying and getting this error message:

> 14:46:25.784 INFO - Marking the node http://17.168.83.211:5555 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try using absolute ip instead of localhost.

Comment: This solved my issue but don't know why localhost was not working

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute ip instead of localhost.